# Remove exact string from end of url apache htaccess rewriterule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have all my URLs like this example: [http://domain.com/="%7b%7bstore](http://domain.com/=%22%7B%7Bstore)

I would like to create a `RewriteRule` to remove the trailing `="%7b%7bstore` from the url.

The string is always at the end. The rule has to leave any other query string, url part untouched.

I figured that `%7b` translates to `{`.

I got this far with the rule, but can't figure out the rest:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)store$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Could anybody help? Thank you!

Comment: Your problem is google indexing same pages with different parameters in the url ?

Comment: No, please ignore that part. I need the rewrite rule only. I edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: Can you give example of **from - to** url to know the pattern you're looking for

Comment: Example: domain.com/="%7b%7bstore > domain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule as your first rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*?)="\{\{store(.*)$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please confirm that this will ONLY match ="%7b%7bstore on the very end of the URL? I have tested this redirect and it seems to be working but I would like to be 100% sure.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*?)="\{\{store(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L] -- This seems to be working better. "NE" was incorrectly converting characters in the url.

Comment: I corrected it accordingly and to answer your previous comment yes it will only match `/="%7b%7bstore` URI.