# htaccess - redirect directory and remove matching string form end of SEF url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to use .htaccess to redirect directory structure and remove this string "-detail" from the end of all SEF url.

for example:

```
https://www.example1.com/shop/items/product-catalog/category/concrete-tiles-detail
```

redirect to

```
https://www.example2.com/product-catalog/category/concrete-tiles
```

The "category" part of the path is dynamic. and could even be comprised of several directories like

```
https://www.example1.com/shop/items/product-catalog/category1-2-or-3/sub-category/concrete-tiles-detail
```

the first rule works, but i have not found a solution for removing the string at the end.i tried [this](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268906/remove-exact-string-from-end-of-url-apache-htaccess-rewriterule) answer but its not working for this scenario.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^shop/items/product-catalog/(.*) https://www.example2.com/product-catalog/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)="\{\{-detail(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding that part after the grouped match in the pattern (and anchoring the pattern at the end), should do the trick.

```
RewriteRule ^shop/items/product-catalog/(.*)-detail$ https://www.example2.com/product-catalog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That second rule you tried, can be removed completely then.

Comment: sorry, let me make it more clear.
the "/category/" part of the path is dynamic. it could be 
https://www.example1.com/shop/items/product-catalog/shoes/concrete-tiles-detail  or https://www.example1.com/shop/items/product-catalog/tiles/concrete-tiles-detail or https://www.example1.com/shop/items/product-catalog/tiles/blue/concrete-tiles-detail

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Accoprding to https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, your first example here should get rewritten to `https://www.example2.com/product-catalog/shoes/concrete-tiles` now. How is that not what you want?